# MongoDB Altas Auto-Increment fields with Trigger unknown: Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Tags: mongodb, triggers, mongodb-atlas

I want to implement auto-incremented fields with MongoDB Atlas triggers. However, by following the instruction from [official MongoDB website](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment). I still face an error `> error: unknown: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (46:18)` message as I run the code in the setting of trigger. The line number is pointing to the first line of await function. Below is the function I write for setting the trigger. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
exports = function(changeEvent) {
    var docId = changeEvent.fullDocument._id;
    
    const countercollection = context.services.get("Cluster0").db("test").collection("counters");
    const samplecollection = context.services.get("Cluster0").db("test").collection("samples");
    
    var counter = await countercollection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: changeEvent.ns },{ $inc: { seq_value: 1 }}, { returnNewDocument: true, upsert : true});
    var updateRes = await samplecollection.updateOne({_id : docId},{ $set : { sampleId: counter.seq_value}});
    
    console.log(`Updated ${JSON.stringify(changeEvent.ns)} with counter ${counter.seq_value} result : ${JSON.stringify(updateRes)}`);
};
```

[The counter collection in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSthL.png)

Comment: The docs you point to show their function is created as `async` but yours is not. Is that difference on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the "async" keyword before the function statement:

[image]

[https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment#:~:text=To%20ensure%20your%20database%20remains,can%20result%20in%20data%20duplication](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment#:%7E:text=To%20ensure%20your%20database%20remains,can%20result%20in%20data%20duplication).